# PG::ConnectionBad FATAL: role "Myname" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost

I am trying to use PostgreSQL so that I can deploy to Heroku. However I cannot run localhost anymore why? I get the following message:

```
PG::ConnectionBad
FATAL: role "Myname" does not exist
```

Here is my databse.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

# Use pg as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

It seems that pg needs me to create a user or databse however I am unable to or don't know how. Couldn't find any commands that worked for me(I'm on a windows btw)

What can I do?

Comment: You should give `username` and `password` to your `database.yml` file

Comment: how do I know what my password is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go into my PG admin dashboard and create a db/user there. Unfrotunately it was in a subdirectory different from what the tutorials online said(probably updated directory destination last update). Fortunately I was able to find it and create the table/user there, update my database.yml file and then my app was able to work!

Answer (score 64):

***The error is "role "Myname" does not exist",***

create the user "Myname" for Postgresql

> sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser Myname

**it will solve this issue.**

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me was: `createuser -P -d -e Myname`.

```
-P  If given, createuser will issue a prompt for the password of the new user.
      This is not necessary if you do not plan on using password authentication.
-d  The new user will be allowed to create databases.
-e  Echo the commands that createuser generates and sends to the server.
```

If you install Postgresql with homebrew on OSX, there is no default `postgres` user, and you won't be able to use `psql` directly without setting up a user first.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command to use your Postgres Shell:

> sudo su - postgres

Now use this command to create a user:

> createuser -s -r 'user_name'

Now *logout*.

**The error is resolved.**

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, I believe it is a little easier.

Install postgresql and PGAdmin for your system. See [this](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows)

Create a user named postgres and give it a password. You will be nicely prompted to do this.

Then, when you want to [create databases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wvDVBjNDys), just right click on your connection and choose New Database. The names of these databases should correspond to what is written in your `database.yml`

Run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` (development| test| production).

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `username` and `password` for your `Postgresql`

Try creating a user with password in `psql`

```
CREATE USER Myname WITH PASSWORD 'your_password';
```

And your should add those to your `database.yml` as

```
username: Myname
password: your_password
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3408293

1. After the installation create a user for postgresql

   sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER

   sudo -u postgres createuser pgs_root
2. Set user password for the postgresql user

   sudo -u postgres psql postgres

   ( For psql prompt) postgres=# \passsword for ex.- postgres=# \passsword pgs_root

N.B  You should also add username and password to different environments in database.yml file.

You can also refer this link: [Rails: Error installing pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439207/rails-error-installing-pg-gem/11440210#11440210)

Comment: sudo command does not work on my computer. Believe it does not work on windows

Comment: This might help you. http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Comment: actually I use gitbash on a windows machine not windows command line sorry should have specified. This sucks pretty much I can't do anything..

Comment: Get rid of it or else you will be in deep trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. For me, I had installed postgresql@10 via home-brew. What I did was run

```
initdb -D /what/ever/path/you/choose
```

to set up postgres and then I started postgres in my terminal via

```
postgres -D /that/same/path/used/in/initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating postgres user didn't work for me as mentioned in other answers.
Try if you could do `psql` in your repo. If not try exporting your database

```
export PGDATABASE=postgres PGHOST=localhost PGUSER=deploy PGPASSWORD=pass
```

This fixed it for me.