# Trouble when migrating DB on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm trying to create an online store for my brother on rails and when i try to migrate my db this error pop up

```
rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "manuel" does not exist
/home/manuel/Shopper/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/manuel/Shopper/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/manuel/Shopper/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Caused by:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "manuel" does not exist
/home/manuel/Shopper/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/manuel/Shopper/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/manuel/Shopper/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer. It should help you fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841599/9104680

Comment: Thanks man it worked perfectly, and also thanks for the corrections

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PG::ConnectionBad FATAL: role "Myname" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338356/pgconnectionbad-fatal-role-myname-does-not-exist)