# Rails6 New app Postgres Database Connection Issue Peer authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm using `rails 6.1` and `ruby 3.1.1` on `ubuntu 22.04`

I've started a new rails app using Postgres: `rails new lmt --database=postgresql`

I also ran `gem install pg`

I have postgres on my local machine and have previously created the dbs: `lmt_production, lmt_development, and lmt_test`.  They all use the user `lmt`.  `lmt` was granted `all privileges` on all dbs.

When I run `rails s`, it generated this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "jdc44" does not exist
):
```

I added the `lmt` username to the `database.yml` for all three dbs and now I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "lmt"
):
```

I understand the `user` issue, but can't find any help on `peer`.

This is all on my dev site (local machine).  I haven't pushed anything to heroku yet.

I had another app that used this same database. I did not have any issues with that setup.

Thoughts?

My Database.yml file:

```
# hard-coding the database and username for testing

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: lmt_development
  username: lmt

test:
  <<: *default
  database: lmt_test
  username: lmt

production:
  <<: *default
  database: lmt_production
  username: lmt
  password: <%= ENV['MY_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

[PG::ConnectionBad FATAL: role "Myname" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338356/pgconnectionbad-fatal-role-myname-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by comparing my old app that used postres. It took awhile to see the obvious. The `database.yml` in the new app did not have a `localhost` entry.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

  host: localhost
  username: lmt
  password: <%= ENV['MY_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Sigh!